# What rarity are Theme Recipe Fragments?

Tags: fallout-shelter

On Quests, Theme Recipe Fragments might be found. However, their rarity isn't a usual one. **So, what rarity are they?**
[image: Theme Recipe Fragments]

*They seem to be given special importance, as a rarer object does; they always get on the "Quest Rewards" Screen.*

Answer (score 1):

Themes are a different 'category' of object and do not have Common/Rare/Legendary classifications (hence the grey backdrop).